# Node listen EPERM operation not permitted

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, compiler-errors

I use beget hosting, write express server

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Terminal result:

```
(docker) s999922k_ssh@splinter:~/io.s999922k.beget.tech [0] $ node app/app.js
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EPERM: operation not permitted :::8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1380:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1428:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1516:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/s/s999922k/io.s999922k.beget.tech/app/app.js:10:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1407:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EPERM',
  errno: -1,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}

Node.js v17.9.0
```

Why???

Раньше я пользовался hostland.pro, не помню чтобы там была такая проблема. Хотя там так де всё работало через Passenger

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please write the complete content in English on StackOverflow!